# Interpretation - Wall Street Is Missing the Risk to Stocks If Inflation Is Beaten

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

Please help analyze the intention of this sentence from Bloomberg News.

[Wall Street Is Missing the Risk to Stocks If Inflation Is Beaten](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-10-08/wall-street-is-missing-the-risk-to-stocks-if-inflation-is-beaten?srnd=markets-vp)

> The conventional wisdom with stock bulls is that prices will take off when the Federal Reserve wins its fight against inflation. But the end of surging consumer costs could unleash another round of bad news.

Does *missing the risk* here mean that Wall Street is free from any risk to stocks if inflation is beaten? Or does it instead mean that Wall Street should consider the risk to stocks if inflation is beaten—but is not doing so?

I realize that *missing* can have multiple meanings, but I am unsure which one of these three is the one that the author intends:

1. Missing the target (did not achieve the goal e.g. company revenue missed the target 100 million dollar).
2. Missing someone.
3. Missing the point. (Meaning that someone either does not understand the important point or else does not consider it)

To me the author appears to be mixing both positive and negative sentiment plus repeating capital `I` in `Is, If, Inflation, Is`. Is the author playing with words to make it look fancy?

Comment: Doesn't the quoted passage clearly imply that the intended meaning is the latter?

Comment: missing the risk means: not understanding the risk

Comment: It's an awkward sentence, probably because it's a title. Investors (Wall Street) apparently believe that a reduction in inflation will causes stocks to rise. However, they didn't factor in consumer costs, which will continue to hold down stocks. They just missed that factor entirely.

Comment: Regarding capital letters: American practice in headlines is to capitalize almost everything, including words like *if* and *is* but usually not *the* and *to.* In a British headline, editors rarely capitalise outside the normal rules of "First word and proper nouns." [The two spellings of one particular word in this comment are deliberate.]

Answer (score 3):

The important word is *missing*, a form of the verb *miss*. The sense is this one:

[M-W *miss*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss)
verb
**5: to fail to comprehend, sense, or experience**

So. *missing the risk*  means not sensing or understanding the risk for stocks  if the fed is successful in beating inflation.

The phrase *missing the point* isn't the meaning of this use, rather, it's another use of the same sense of *miss*.

There's no word-play I can see there. The capitalization is just headline formatting.